# Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am getting this error "**Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type.**" intermittently in a SP designer Reusable workflow.This workflow is triggered on item Added and the workflow has a single step of sending email to user who created this item. The email has few values of few fields from the item in the body. This issue happens intermittently.. like i got this error in WF for a particular item in the first run when item was added.Then  i manually started the WF again on that same item and it was Successful. For some items in the first Run also the WF worked perfectly.

Comment: Any clues on this?  Did you ever solve it?